# How can I add pagination using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paging

I want to implement simple pagination using jQuery. I get the data from a jQuery ajax call, I tried for the same but it is not working. Here is my working code & let me know what i missed in this.
    [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/113/)

Here is code for paging

```
pageSize = 8;
            var pageCount = $(".portlet").length / pageSize;
            for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li> ');
            }
            $("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current")
            showPage = function (page) {
                $(".line-content").hide();
                $(".line-content").each(function (n) {
                    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                        $(this).show();
                });
            }
            showPage(1);
            $("#pagin li a").click(function () {
                $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");
                showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
            });
```

Comment: 'It is not working' is not very helpful.  What *does* it do?

Comment: Data is not display with paging

Comment: your `pagecount` returns `0.25` which is less than 1 so your for loop not working

Answer (score 0):

Your `pagecount` returns 0.25 which is less than 1 so your for loop not working. Use `Math.ceil` to round of your `pagecount` Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/118/).

```
 var pageCount = Math.ceil($(".portlet").length / pageSize);
 for (var i = 0; i <= pageCount; i++) {
     $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li> ');
 }
```

Comment: Yes now it count properly but, how will i display data in paging

Comment: You can set items per page like 4 on page load and add class or some attribute ti rest of items same as page number. On page number click just show items having page number 2

Comment: dint get you, could you pls explain

Comment: It's not working, means it showing paging nos but when i click on next page no it shows blank

Comment: It is showing items for me in this fiddle on page number click http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/128/

Comment: yes it is, but on my web page on page load it hide the (.portlet div)

Comment: make sure you add your pagination code after this line `$('#container').html(output); $("div.portlet[page!='1']").hide();` where page is attribute to `.portlet` div....

Comment: yes i added that line , but still it won't work, it should show the attribute page="" to that div, right? it not showing page attribute

Comment: have you updated this line also `output += '<div class="portlet light bg-inverse tripcontainer" page="'+(key+1)+'"><div class="row">';`

Comment: I put paging on top & bottom of div but it works only 1 paging at a time, means, if i click 2 on top paging then it should be active bottom paging on page 2

Comment: Can you share your updated fiddle? You should use classes in that case

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/135/, also if i have more 4 page results then paging should show 1 2 3 4 ....... 10,  but now its showing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 0):

Jon, you are looking for .portlet which is not attached to the DOM yet.

//Edit:
I'm not sure why you are looking for .line-content which is not part of your code. But I've changed your code as small as possible and now seems working. http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/131/

I've moved

```
$('#container').html(output);
```

before pagination part, and I've changed:

```
var pageCount = Math.ceil($(".portlet").length / pageSize);
```

and also showPage was looking for wrong class:

```
showPage = function (page) {
                $(".portlet ").hide();
                $(".portlet ").each(function (n) {
                    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                        $(this).show();
                });
            }
```

Comment: yes, i think i missed something or placement of paging function is wrong, could you pls help me in this?

Comment: @BaQ
If I have more thane 4 page results then paging should show 1 2 3 4 ....... 10, but now its showing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code.

//Pagination

```
pageSize = 4;

var pageCount = Math.ceil(data.driver_data.length / pageSize);

for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li> ');
}
$("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current")

showPage = function (page) {
    $(".portlet").hide();
        $(".portlet").each(function (n) {
            if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                $(this).show();
        });
    }

$("#pagin li a").click(function () {
    $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
});
$('#container').html(output);
showPage(1);
```

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcq8h7b2/126/)

Comment: No, If I have more thane 4 page results then paging should show 1 2 3 4 ....... 10, but now its showing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 0):

I made a codepen with exactly this functionality. I will give you a complete breakdown of the code here as well.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Neil_Meyer_ZA/pen/poEaEYo)

```js
// Here we first declare an array from which we are going to do the pagination.

var animals = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dog',
    type: 'Mammal'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Cat',
    type: 'Mammal'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Goat',
    type: 'Mammal'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Lizard',
    type: 'Reptile'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Frog',
    type: 'Amphibian'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Spider',
    type: 'Arachnid'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Crocodile',
    type: 'Reptile'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Tortoise',
    type: 'Reptile'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Barracuda',
    type: 'Fish'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Sheep',
    type: 'Mammal'
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: 'Lion',
    type: 'Mammal'
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Seal',
    type: 'Mammal'
  }
];

// Here are some more variables which we would need to paginate between the various items in the array.

var pageSize = 2;
var currentPage = 1;
var pagedResults = [];
var totalResults = animals.length;

// Page Size indicates the amount of items we want on a page.

// Current Page indicates the curren page that is being shown.

// Paged Results indicates an array that contains the section of the animal array, which represents the page.

// Total Results indicates the amount of items in the array.

$(function() {
  function updateList() {

    // Grab the required section of results from the animals list
    var end = (currentPage * pageSize);
    var start = (end - pageSize);
    pagedResults = animals.slice(start, end);

    // Empty the list element before repopulation
    $('#list').empty();

    // Disable the previous button if we are on the first page
    if (currentPage <= 1) {
      $('.previous').prop("disabled", true);
    }

    // Enable the previous button if we are not on the first page
    else {
      $('.previous').prop("disabled", false);
    }

    // Disable the next button if we are on the last page
    if ((currentPage * pageSize) >= totalResults) {
      $('.next').prop("disabled", true);
    }

    // Enable the next button if we are not on the last page
    else {
      $('.next').prop("disabled", false);
    }

    //Loop through the pages results and add them to the list
    $.each(pagedResults, function(index, obj) {
      $('#list').append("<li><strong>" + obj.name + "</strong> (" +
        obj.type + ")</li>");
    });
  }

  //Populate the list on load
  updateList();
  $('.next').click(function() {

    //Only increase the current page if there are enough results
    if ((currentPage * pageSize) <= totalResults) currentPage++;
    updateList();
  });
  $('.previous').click(function() {

    //Only decrease the current page if it is currently greater than 1
    if (currentPage > 1) currentPage--;
    updateList();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list"></ul>
<button class="previous"> << Previous</button>
<button class="next">Next >></button>
```